# To prove that a hopfian group is not free.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, hopfian

In the book "presentation of groups by johnson" in page $36$ they are trying to obtain a group that is locally free but not free (Example $2$).They have proved that the group $U=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n$ is hopfian. Upto that I have understood. But I could not understand why the group $U$ is not free. It is described in line 17,18 and 19 on page $36$. Can anyone please explain it? and please refer the book for reference.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you probably meant you couldn't understand why the group $\;U\;$ **isn't free** ...? I mean, because what Johnson does is to prove  it actually isn't.

Comment: It is proved in the book that $U$ is not free, so you should make it clear which step in the proof you do not understand.

Comment: @DerekHolt I couldn't understand how $U$ is atmost countably generated?and how that concludes $U$ cannot be free of rank $\aleph_0$?

Comment: It is a union of countably many countable groups and therefore countable. It cannot be free of rank $\aleph_0$ because the free group of rank $\aleph_0$ is easily seen to be nonHopfian.

Comment: @DerekHolt But I am not getting why $U$ has to be generated by countably infinite generators. The number of generators of $U$ should be finite because each $F_n$ has rank $\leqslant r$ and $F_n \subseteq F_{n+1}$, $\forall n$. So, what is the need of considering that $F$ of rank $\aleph_0$.

Comment: It would be nice if you outlined the construction of the group to make this question self contained. If I had to guess, any finite set of elements will generate some subgroup of some $F_n$ (in the union) which is not the full group, so it has to be countably infinitely generated.

Comment: As Paul Plummer says, it is a union of a strictly ascending sequence of subgroups, so it cannot be finitely generated.

Comment: @DerekHolt But the strictly ascending sequence of subgroups that you are talking about are each having rank $\leqslant r$

Comment: It doesn't matter. It is easy to show that a union of a strictly ascending infinite sequence of subgroups cannot be finitely generated.

Comment: The rational numbers, as an additive group, is an ascending union of cyclic groups, but it is definitely not cyclic, or finitely generated.

Comment: @PaulPlummer Thank you very much. I got it. And can you please tell me what is the meaning of proper union?